# Is @Import annotation necessary with Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm working with Spring Boot 2.1.5. I have multiple classes annotated with `@Configuration`.

I want to know if it's necessary to list all of these configuration classes with `@Import`? Or will the component scanner find all the `@Configuration` annotated classes and do it *automatically*?

Comment: Nope it is not .

Answer (score 5):

You don’t need to do that, scanning will be done for you automatically , all you need is to make your main class on the root package, and all other stereotypes classes including configuration  in sub packages

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary to use @Import annotation.  As the @Configuration is a Meta-annotation for @Component , the Component scanner will pick it . But Spring docs suggest to use @Import annotation when you have many @Configuration classes. This is just for better management.